# Transparent failover for NFS home directory (with LDAP users)

Tags: linux, rsync, nfs

**Background:**
In our work environment, we have LDAP users together with NFS homes. So you sign on LDAP server, autofs mounts the homes, etc. Pretty neat so far. However, from time to time, the NFS or LDAP server is down. Approx. 10 days per year. On those days I damn the whole system, as I can't login accessing my data in the home folder. But on other days, it happend 2 times within 6 years, I needed the backup from my home folder.
What I want now is: How to use the home folder in a transparent way? When systems are available, I want to work as if I were on the home folder, But when NFS server or LDAP server is down I want still beeing able to access my system and data.

It is clear, that if remote authentication does not work, I can only login with a local user account. As the shares are accessed via NFS, I just need to take care, that my local user has same UID and GID, and everything is fine, right?

But for the NFS share, things are different. When the server is down, and I want to access my data, I need a copy. (Probably in the local home directory). But how do I sync when NFS server is back online?

The simplest solution so far seems to use a CRON job employing rsync and autofs. Do you know any better?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the NFS server, you could try using something like BTSync to sync local and remote directories. It employs bittorent protocol, pretty light on traffic and uses encryption.

It's still in the beta though, so you could *hypothetically* run into some issues.

http://www.bittorrent.com/sync